# Like Box Body Text Color

Tags: colors, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

I can't get the actual text of my like box stream to display in white using the "dark" color scheme.

The title and all links etc look fine but the main body of the post is in either black or very dark grey so is pretty much unreadable.

```
    <div style="background-color:#000000;" class="fb-like-box" 

data-href="http://www.facebook.com/wecouldbeastronauts" data-width="260" data-height="250" data-colorscheme="dark" 

data-show-faces="false" data-border-color="#000000" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
```

is my code. I visited the facebook dev site again to remake it thinking I must have got it wrong but that has the same issue.

Comment: `grey` (aka `#999`) hardly can be named *"black or very dark grey"*, are you sure your monitor is calibrated?

Comment: I've just had this from a client too, the .messageBody text is #333333 and virtually unreadable on the dark background?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to alter colors for content within social plugins, so you have no option other than stick to original color schemes Facebook provides `light` and `dark`.

In `dark` scheme text of stories colored `grey` (aka `#999`) which should be seen perfectly  on black background (well, for people comfortable with dark backgrounds)...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the comments plugin shows text as super dark gray no matter if I select "light" OR "dark." Both look like this:

http://scrubclubrecords.com/example.jpg

Is there a place where we can edit the default "light" and "dark" css this pulls from somehow?